# Factory restore Windows 7 without erasing Ubuntu on Toshiba dual-boot

Tags: multi-boot, windows-7-restore

I have Ubuntu and Windows 7 dual-boot system on my laptop.

When I bought it I immediately created recovery discs. Then I repartitioned and installed Ubuntu.

Now my Windows is running slowly and I suspect some malware is running there even though I'm not sure. So I would like to return my Windows installation to factory defaults WITHOUT erasing Ubuntu.

I'm pretty sure that I would have to reinstall Grub but this is not a big problem.

Is it possible to do just that? Restore Windows without touching other partitions on a Toshiba R830?

Comment: Why don't you just reinstall Windows 7 on the Windows 7 partition? Simple enough to get installation media and do it yourself.

Comment: [Where do I download Windows 7 (legally from Microsoft)?](http://superuser.com/questions/78761/where-do-i-download-windows-7-legally-from-microsoft)

Answer (score 0):

Probably not using the recovery discs, since they were created before partitioning. And like +Ramhound said, I know the Windows installer is capable of not nuking other partitions. But then you might be stuck trying to shuffle drivers around if it doesn't have your ethernet drivers on it. Small pain, and rarer with desktops.

In either case: I would use a tool like Norton Ghost to copy your Ubuntu partition before attempting any restore. This way you could restore, and if it nukes Ubuntu, just resize and restore the partition.

But knowing Windows installers/restorers, you'll have to reinstall the boot manager to get back in to Ubuntu.